# How to implement Shopify - Customer Login in React-Native or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, authentication, shopify

I'm working on React-Native application with Shopify. In this application Customers (who will buy the products) is the only target user.

I wanted to implement a Login mechanism for customer but unable to find Shopify API for the same.

I have already gone through [Storefront API](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/custom-storefronts/storefront-api/reference) and [Customer API](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/customers/customer)

Could you please guide me here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this.

Prerequisites:

- While integrating Shopify customer login, **that respective customer must have a shop/store in Shopify**.
- Also, as there isn't any specific support to create a Shopify app for mobile application, **the backend should integrate the Shopify app and give the Redirection URL to the frontend**.

Steps:

1. I've created a Shopify Connect button, if a user clicks on it, **we should ask a user to put a Shopify Shop/Store Name**(this shop/store name is **mandatory**).
2. Once a user fills Shop/Store Name and **clicks on the submit** button, I'm calling my **backend API which gives me a Callback URL** in a response(which is a **Shopify URL**. This Shopify URL starts with `https://${shop_name}.myshopify.com` and **this URL also contains some query params having redirect_uri**).
3. Then I called this whole **Callback URL on a Webview**([RN Webview](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview)).
4. **Users will see a Shopify login page** if that respective user's shop/store name is listed in Shopify. Then the user can log in and allow my application to access Shopify details of that particular user.
5. Once the user's **authentication is done, Shopify calls the Redirection URL**(this URL we've to whitelist while creating a Shopify App). We've specified backend's HTML page URL as a Redirection URL, to show Success or Failure message. Also, **this Redirection URL is as same as that of redirect_uri**(provided that the query params are ignored) which I get in the query params of the Callback URL in step 2.
6. Now in the **RN Webview, a prop onNavigationStateChange** is called whenever Webview's state is changed. **Using this prop, I figured out that Shopify Authentication is done, and Webview's URL is now changed to Redirection URL**(ie redirect_uri).
7. As soon as I figured out the Webview's URL is as same as the Redirection URL(provided that the query params are ignored), **I showed the Webview for 3-5 seconds(Success or Failure Screen on Webview) and then I popped the Webview Screen from the React Navigation stack**.
8. After popping up the Webview Screen, I called my backend API to check the user's status of Shopify integration and accordingly I showed the Alert message.

**This is a properly working example of Shopify Integration that I and my team have integrated using React Native and Python successfully.**

Answer (score 0):

Use customerAccessTokenCreate mutation which will provide you the access token when you pass login credential as an input. This is actually work like login api. Here is the link [https://shopify.dev/docs/storefront-api/reference/mutation/customeraccesstokencreate?api[version]=2020-04](https://shopify.dev/docs/storefront-api/reference/mutation/customeraccesstokencreate?api%5Bversion%5D=2020-04)

Answer (score -1):

Shopify provides a customer login route, so you simply wire up that. No need to re-invent the wheel. Examine any existing Shopify theme for inspiration. No need for any API calls.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Shopify. Could you please add some code example or reference link here. Thanks

Comment: Um no. You have to do your own work. Stackoverflow is not a gift shop. No matter how new you are, you have an obligation to work at your craft. Open up a theme in your editor, and examine the customer login. It is much much easier to do that than it is to render a Hello World React App, so I am sure you can do it.

Comment: Do you want me to load "my-site/account/login" route/URL in Webview (Since this native application) ?

Comment: I can't help you sorry. Your native application will have to either use Shopify to login customers or you're out of luck. There is no facility to login customers any other way, as far as I know.